# How to read a txt file in js and print its lines in different divs

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I've tried.
This should read a txt file and create a div for each line but nothing happens...
I'm sure the array gets all the file text because if I try to console.log it, it's as it should be.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var array = fs.readFileSync("./parts/logs.txt").toString().split("\n");
var temp;

for (i in array) {
  temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.className = 'results';
  temp.innerHTML = array[i];
  document.getElementsById('items').appendChild(temp);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="items"></div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing server side js (node) and browser side. `document` does not exis in nodejs.You need to send the file content from the server (nodejs) to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me. Is document.getElementsById right syntax - shouldn't it be getElementById ?
https://jsfiddle.net/nrd0ojvx/

```
<button onclick="doit()">Do it </button>
<div id='items'>text</div>

<div>end</div>

<script>
function doit(){
var array = ["abc","def"];
var temp;

for (i in array) {
  temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.className = 'results';
  temp.innerHTML = array[i];
  console.log(i,temp);
  document.getElementById('items').appendChild(temp);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thx dude, for some reason I can't get vs code to highlight errors like that one...